# python re split string by commas and space

Tags: python, regex

I need to split a string by commas and spaces. An example of the desired behavior is converting the string `'    5,    3,   , hello'` to the list `['5', '3', 'hello']`. Here's what I tried:

```
import re
re.split(',|\s+', '    5,    3,   , hello')
['', '5', '', '3', '', '', '', 'hello']
```

Why are the blank entries being returned? How can I retrieve the list  `['5', '3', 'hello']`?

Comment: Maybe [`re.split('[\s,]+', s.strip())`](http://ideone.com/7kDmJS) => `['5', '3', 'hello']`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Closer, that returns `['', '5', '3', 'hello']`

Comment: May be you can strip all your strings once you split the main string by commas ?

Comment: Actually, he also wants to get rid of empty strings after that. Something like `[x for x in re.split(',?\s+', s) if x]`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `findall` and match what you want:

```
>>> print re.findall(r'[^,\s]+', '    5,    3,   , hello')
['5', '3', 'hello']
```

`[^,\s]+` is using a negated character class to match any text that is not a comma and not a whitespace.

---

Your split regex `,|\s+` is splitting at multiple positions since `,` is surrounded by whitespaces as well.

As your input has leading whitespaces even splitting on `[,\s]+` will give an empty element at the start.

```
>>> print re.split(r'[,\s]+', '    5,    3,   , hello')
['', '5', '3', 'hello']
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain the findall regex expression please?

Comment: Sure. `[^,\s]+` is using a negated character class to match any text that is not a comma and not a whitespace.

Answer (score 6):

Just for fun, to show a non-regex approach, you can perform this within a comprehension by splitting on `,`, and ignoring any string that passes the [isspace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isspace) check and finally calling `strip` on the final data placed in the list to remove surrounding whitespace.

Taking this in to account, the final solution would look like:

```
>>> s = '    5,    3,   , hello'
>>> res = [c.strip() for c in s.split(',') if not c.isspace()]
>>> res
['5', '3', 'hello']
```

Performing a timeit analysis on the two solutions, we can observe the following:

```
>>> print(timeit('''
... s = '    5,    3,   , hello'
... res = [c.strip() for c in s.split(',') if not c.isspace()]
... '''))
1.681301467004232
>>>
>>> print(timeit('''
... import re
... re.findall(r'[^,\s]+', '    5,    3,   , hello')
... '''))
2.7143720029853284
```

I'm a bit surprised with how big of a difference it is in favour of this non-regex comprehension approach.

Comment: I think if you use a ``map`` instead of list comprehension, this would be even faster.